# convert a large string with escaped chars to a byte array

Tags: c++, escaping, converters

As an example, I have a jpeg represented as a string in the format

`ÿØÿà\\0\x10JFIF\\0\x01\x01\\0\\0\x01\\0\x01`

I want to see this a binary image of the file, i.e. a byte array with values

`FF D8 FF E0 5C 30 10 4A 46 49 46 5C 30 01 01 5C etc.`

Is there some code (C/C++)to do this or must I write it myself :) don't want to reinvent the wheel and I am sure this must have been asked before (although I can't find it)

Comment: Is the quoted hex expected to be the beginning of the result? What is the encoding of string? Assuming single byte ascii: ÿØÿà\0\x10JFIF\0\x01\x01\0\0\x01\0\x01 actually resolves to [c3 bf c3 98 c3 bf c3 a0 5c 30 5c 78 31 30 4a 46 49 46 5c 30 5c 78 30 31 5c 78 30 31 5c 30 5c 30 5c 78 30 31 5c 30 5c 78 30 31]

Answer (score 0):

Just use `std::ostream::write()` method:

```
char str[] = "ÿØÿà\0\x10JFIF\0\x01\x01\0\0\x01\0\x01";
std::ofstream out( "file", ios::bin | ios::out );
out.write( str, sizeof( str ) - 1 ); // assuming you do not need to store leading \0

// or using std::string
std::string str { "ÿØÿà\0\x10JFIF\0\x01\x01\0\0\x01\0\x01", 19 );
std::ofstream out( "file", ios::bin | ios::out );
out.write( str.data(), str.length() );
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood your question, you want that the string becomes converted into a byte array of its codepage equivalents. This is a way you may do it:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

  // You must know the length of your string resp. how many characters it contains.
  // Otherwise it would end at the first \0 character.
  std::string s{ "ÿØÿà\0\x10JFIF\0\x01\x01\0\0\x01\0\x01", 18 };
  std::istringstream ss(s);

  std::vector<unsigned char> byteArray;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; !ss.eof() && i < s.size(); ++i) {
   byteArray.emplace_back(ss.get()); // C++98: byteArray.push_back(ss.get());
  }
  for each (auto byte in byteArray)
  {
   // enforce byte to be treated as a number by putting it in a dummy addition expression
   std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << 0 + byte << " "; 
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
```

This leads to the following output using VS2013:

```
  ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01
```